# Multiple optional parameters in discord.py

Tags: python, parameters, discord.py, optional-parameters

I want a command that does

/profile (optional) (optional 2)

/profile  -> will give the profile of myself

/profile personA -> will give the profile of personA

/profile 2019 -> will give the profile of myself in 2019

/profile personA 2019 -> will give the profile of personA in 2019

currently i have only done the first and i need help adding the optional parameters

```
async def profile(self, ctx):  
print("profile")
```

Comment: Check the profile of a `member` with `discord.Member`, in your case `personA`. What do you mean with "*will give the profile of xxx in 2019*"?

Comment: im making the profile for a game. so the original profile has the stats of every year while a optional parameter will filter the data of only that year

Comment: What is your data source? Where are you getting this data from? You can also create a simple parameter for it, like `date : int` or something similar, and then query it in your code. This is not about the parameters, but how the rest of your code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Use [typing.Optional](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=typing%20optional#typing-optional) for optional arguments. The values not passed will be None.

/profile -> both arguments will be None
/profile personA -> member will be personA, year will be None
/profile 2019 -> member will be None, year will be 2019
/profile personA 2019 -> member will be personA, year will be 2019

Then you can check if member is None and if it is assign ctx.author to member.

```
from typing import Optional

async def profile(self, ctx, member: Optional[discord.Member], year: Optional[int]):
    if member is None:
        member = ctx.author
    ...
```

As for how to display the profile, it is dependent on how you are storing data and would probably be too broad/off-topic here.